# Get progress of omxplayer

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there a way to get the second omxplayer has already played (e.g for a Progressbar)?

If I press <kbd>p</kbd>, the video pauses. Is there a key like this for the progress?

I am using omxplayer in a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

```
omxplayer -s
```

will send state information including seconds

```
M: 8516603 V: -8.52s      0k/     0k A:  4.67   4.63s/  6.07s Cv:     0k Ca:   180k
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it'll be useful for you, but [Pyomxplayer](https://github.com/jbaiter/pyomxplayer) will do it.

Nevertheless, it's essentially a Python wrapper around OMXPlayer and I'm not sure that's OK for you.